# Ubuntu sidebar on desktop stopped showing

Tags: compiz

I decided to give Ubuntu a try after all these years using only Windows as OS.

I downloaded that windows installer from their site and installed Ubuntu. Everything went well until I decided to update the drivers and apps. It seems to be a bad idea, because I can't see the sidebar anymore (the one with the "quick launch options") and some graphic elements from the OS are not present, like the top bar with the clock.

Another issue: I always see an error regarding Compiz after a couple of minutes, saying that it stopped responding.

Am I missing something?

I'm using the 12.10 64bit version.

**EDIT**

I googled about the problem and it seems that Compiz is bugged like hell in 12.10. 
I'm uninstalling it and giving 12.04 a try. That's too bad, because I like many features from this version, specially the use and feel. But I can't stand using it without the left bar and a graphic interface at all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to open system settings, select "appearance", then open the "behaviour" tab, and "Restore Default Behaviours"?
If it doesn't work try this:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
Run `unity --reset`

If still doesn't work try this:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools  
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A couple of things happened: 
-The first step did not work. 
- When I tried to reset unit, a msg came up, telling me unit wasn't installed. Well, after I installed it, the "--reset" command became deprecated =S 
- The third step did not help me either.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and have you tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --replace --reset-icon & disown
```

And it might work fine this way.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar error. The sidebar showed up in the guest session, but not in others. I had removed everything in the `~/.config` folder to resolve the issue, following this guide: 
[How To Fix: No Unity, No Launcher, No Dash In Ubuntu 14.04](http://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/).

Sidebar showed after that automatically, but it hidden after restart system!

Second way: I created new user by adduser command, and copied my essential files to new user's folder

Comment: Removing “everything in the `~/.config` folder” is probably a bit drastic …